# PHP YOURLS preview plugin issue

Tags: php, html, plugins, yourls

I have set up a link shortener website using YOURLS and I installed the plugin Preview URL (by Ozh, the coder). Link here:

https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/wiki/Plugin-%3D-Preview-URL

However, I would like to edit that plugin to force a preview for every URL. I'm not well acquainted with PHP, and I couldn't find a viable solution online (the only other similar plugin doesn't exist anymore). If someone could give me a hand to get this finished, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you're looking to hire someone this is not the right website.

Comment: I am not looking to hire someone (I can't afford it anyhow), but I was wondering if maybe I am taking the wrong approach, since I am not familiar with PHP. So I thought that maybe someone more experienced with PHP or YOURLS in particular could suggest a different approach on how to create this. I am not looking to be spoonfed, but I would appreciate some advice on this.